# Get Value from another Class?

Tags: objective-c, class

i'm trying to get some ideas to get the values generated by the IBAction into one class.

In facts:
There is an IBAction inside the Class named **TabBarController** (type UiTabBarController, embedded with Navigation Controller and generated via StoryBoard) where is possible to set the values of the segment.

The problem is trying to get these values stored in the variable **VideoLIS** from another Class that is switched by **TabBarController**. It's Boolean becuase it will be used as "switch" to get Video or Text that i have to launch.

in TabBarController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

  @interface TabBarController: UITabBarController
 {
     UISegmentedControl *segmentControl;
     @public
     BOOL *videoLIS;
  }

  @property (readwrite) BOOL *videoLIS;
  @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segmentControl;
  @property (nonatomic) BOOL *checkSegmentedControlState;

  -(IBAction) segmentedControlChanged;
  -(BOOL) statoLIS;
  -(BOOL) checkSegmentedControlState;
 @end
```

in TabBarController.m

```
 #import "TabBarController.h"

 @implementation TabBarController

 @synthesize segmentControl;
 @synthesize videoLIS;
 @synthesize checkSegmentedControlState;

 - (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     videoLIS=TRUE;
  }

 -IBAction **segmentedControlChanged**{
        switch (segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {
            case 0:
               videoLIS=TRUE;
               NSLog(**videoLIS** ? @"LIS" : @"Testo");
               break;
            case 1:
               NSLog(@"TEXT Selected");
               videoLIS=FALSE;
               NSLog(**videoLIS** ? @"LIS" : @"Testo");
               break;
            default:
             break;
            }
 }
```

How to get the Value of videoLIS from another class (UIViewController)?

I was considering to use the NSNotification ... or do you have other solutions?
Thanks a lot for your help.

EDIT:
I tried another solution. I dropped this way and moved the UISegmentControl into every ViewControllers, so I have the result inside the Class without worrying about this.So result come now.

Thanks a lot for your hints.

Comment: Use delegation, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648162/setting-uitabbaritem-title-from-uinavigationcontroller) may help.

Comment: So i have to use delegation to handle the TabBarController? As I read your link the people advised to avoid the "TabBarController" provided by XCode and build itself ... is still valid this rule? (the post is from 2011)

In XCode 7 is possible to handle the View Hierarchy? I know it's visible in real time? Thanks

Comment: I may have misunderstood the question. Please visit this link regarding preloading and such: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23900284/ios-pass-data-from-tabbarcontroller-to-viewcontroller-in-storyboard